# Command works from a terminal but not in .profile

Tags: x11, login, xfce

I included this command in my .profile file: `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon`. The `.profile` runs at startup as expected, but it's unable to run this command (which is the last in the file, so other commands can not be in its way).

However, when I run `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon` on my terminal, in the same way, not being root, it starts the power manager above, with GUI and all.

What can I do to make it run on every boot?

Answer (score 3):

This command must be started after the GUI environment has been started. The file `.profile` is read at the start of your login session, just before starting the GUI environment.

You should instead use the GUI methods to start GUI applications. Go to Settings Manager, Session and Startup; look for Application Autostart tab, press Add. Fill the Name and command to run fields (description is optional) click OK and restart. Now the command should run whenever you start xfce.